# Linux dnsmasq and Windows

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq, dhcp-server

I have a Pi Buster OS (debian variant) in which I use dnsmasq and it is configured as a DHCP server.

I have Pi connected to laptop like a null mode. When Pi starts up, it is all good and PC soon sees its network adapter to Pi as an APIPA address (169.254.xxx.xxx) type.

Soon, it takes PC about 10 to 20 seconds before its APIPA gets an IP address from Pi. At this point, my laptop can ssh into the Pi.

Is there a way that I can speed up this process where the APIPA changes to a valid DCHP quicker? Under 5 to 10 seconds would be great; or is this a Windows hard coded default where it takes time to ask DHCP for an IP which is beyond our control?

Help please? Thanks.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, the PC is on at the time you boot the pi. Since you are using your pi as a DHCP server. it really should be on all the time if you are going to use it that way.

Comment: @FrankThomas Mine has two use cases. 

1/ Pi is on first then PC comes on next and I plug a cable to the Pi then I wait for the link to be established.

2/ PC comes on first then Pi is on next. Like before, I plug a cable to Pi then I wait for the link to be established.

I can configure the Pi as a device with a built in DHCP where the PC is the on its subnet.

The intention is, PC gets an address from the Pi DHCP and PC can start talking to the Pi and vice versa.

I have done the above but PC has an APIPA and takes 10 seconds to get a proper IP address. How to make this faster?

Comment: @FrankThomas sorry, I saw your message the other day but got distracted until I remembered this today. Between Linux and Pi, sometimes this proper IP address appears within seconds like under 5s but on Windows this can take 10 to 15 seconds. 

I am wondering if there is any other way to make this APIPA change  to a proper IP address faster on a PC like under 5 second. I did some reading that I may disable the name server on dnsmasq and see. The alternative is I have the MAC address shown on the PC to Pi and maybe I can also tell dnsmasq that that MAC should have this particular IP.

Comment: Personally I think its rather amazing that this works fine with only a 15-20 second delay, rather than a reboot or command line IP renewal command. I'm actually a little impressed with the windows zero-conf support. Sorry, I don't have any ideas for you other than leaving the pi on and connected to the network at all times if its going to be your DHCP server. perhaps you want to move DHCP services to another device that won't be so transient on your network.

Comment: @FrankThomas Is windows zero-conf support mDNS? Unfortunately, it is not possible for me to use DHCP to a different device. My device is like a tool in which connects to the PC; think of this device as the guest. From there onwards, the host operates the guest.

Comment: mDNS is one of the protocols that support the zero-conf/AVAHI/Bonjour protocol family, yes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf

Comment: Then maybe have the guest use AVAHI (linux zeroconf flavor) instead of having it offer DHCP services and using a static non-apipa?